# Prove continuity of a bounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces, linear-transformations

This is an excercise that I'm trying to solve:

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $M: X \rightarrow X$ a linear map. Prove that M is bounded if and only if there exists a set $ S \subset X'$(the dual space), dense in $X'$, such that for each $\ell \in S$ the functional $m_{\ell}$ defined by:
$m_{\ell}(x)=\ell(Mx), x \in X$ is continuous in $X$.

I think that one can use the closed graph theorem once $m_{\ell}$ is extended to all of $X'$ but I'm not sure how this extension can be done.
I know this: Since $S$ is dense in $X'$ there is for every epsilon an $\ell \in S$ such that $\parallel f - \ell \parallel_{X'} < \epsilon, \forall f \in X'$.
I thought that boundedness off $f$ could be shown by this inequality:
$|f(x)|=|f(x)-\ell(x) +\ell(x)| \leq |f(x)-\ell(x)| +| \ell(x)| $.

Here I thougth that it might be possible to use the uniform boundedness principle, but I'm not sure how. If somebody could help me I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is right.

Let's use the closed graph theorem. Suppose $x_n\to 0$ and $Mx_n\to y$. We have to show that $y=0$, and for this we use Hahn-Banach: It suffices to show that for every $L\in X'$, $Ly=0$.

First, given $\ell\in S$, we have $\ell Mx_n\to \ell y$, but $\ell M=m_\ell$ is continuous by assumption and $x_n\to 0$, so $\ell Mx_n\to 0$ which implies $\ell y=0$.

Now given arbitrary $L\in X'$, take $\ell_i\in S$ with $\ell_i\to L$ (in your problem, in norm, but weak-$*$ convergence is enough), so $Ly=\lim\ell_i y=0$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Why do you assume $x_n \to 0$ and not an arbitrary x? Where and how is the Hahn-Banach theorem used?

Comment: That's how people usually use the closed graph theorem: If $x_n\to x$ and $Mx_n\to z$, we can translate everything by $x$ (and $Mx$), and conclude, by the above argument, that since $x_n-x\to 0$ and $M(x_n-x)\to z-Mx$, we have $z-Mx=0$, i.e., $z=Mx$ as necessary. We use the following version of Hahn-Banach: If $y\neq 0$, then there exists a bounded linear functional $L$ with $Ly=1$.

Comment: Ok I think I get it! The fact that $\forall \ell \in X', \ell(x)=0 \implies x=0$ follows from the Hahn Banach theorem, and that is what you use? Convergence to any $x$ follows from translation? Is it enough in general when one uses the closed graph theorem, to show that it is true for $x_n \to 0$?

Comment: @user202542 Yes. Yes. Yes (and my previous comment explains why it is enough).